# JQuery: Resize image based on browser resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to resize an image based on the size/resizing of the browser using JQuery.

I want the image to scale and maintain it's ratio and not get cut off.

I'm using Bootstrap and my HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm">
          <div class="text-block">
            <h1>Hellow World</h1>
            <h6>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm img-container">
          <img src="image.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm">
          <div class="text-block">
          <h6>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</h6>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

The image is within the `.img-container` div and my JQuery looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(window).resize(function() {
     var img = $("img");
     var image = $(".img-container").find(img);
     var browserRatio =  $(this).width() / $(this).height();
     var imageRatio = image.width() / image.height();

     if(browserRatio > imageRatio) {
       $(".img-container").find(img).css({ "width": "100%", "height": "auto"});
     }
     else if(imageRatio > browserRatio) {
       $(".img-container").find(img).css({ "width": "auto", "height": "100%"});
     }

     console.log("Browser ratio is :" + browserRatio);
     console.log("Image ratio is:" + imageRatio);
   });
});
```

As you can see I am grabbing the height/width ratio of the browser as it resizes and then checking if the image's ratio is greater or less than the ratio of the browser and then attempting to adjust it using css.

This is not working and the width of the image is not maintaining it's ratio. What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Is the image size dynamic or will you know the ratio in advance?

Comment: Dynamic. Starts small and as the browser is made bigger the image grows and starts to creep into the neighboring div's space and the neighboring divs become smaller.

Comment: Do you know the aspect radio in advance?

Comment: The initial image is 450 X 750

Comment: The video doesn't make sense.  Do you want the center item to never grow bigger than 450x750?

Comment: This is a job interview take home assignment. Honestly, I'm a little confused by it myself. Trying my best to emulate what is going on in the video and I'm stumped.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sd0zokmf/1/ is as close as I got, but since there isn't really a defined question it's really hard to answer.

Answer (score -1):

Recently I have answered the same question by simply using CSS https://jsfiddle.net/nazimboudeffa/j6kwtgxa/

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. The image has two divs on each side and needs to maintain it's height/width ratio even as the two neighboring divs change size.

Comment: Did you tryed to change `img` by `div` in my example ?